# Firebase implemented through Segment, Expo React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, firebase-analytics, segment

```
"expo": "^38.0.0",
"react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-38.0.2.tar.gz",
"expo-analytics-segment": "8.2.1",
```

I got Segment initialized on my app as follow

```
Segment.initialize({
  androidWriteKey: androidWriteKeyLocal,
  iosWriteKey: iosWriteKeyLocal,
});
```

identifying users as follow

```
Segment.identifyWithTraits(
  'email',
   {
     country: 'country',
   },
);
```

email is resized by this rules

```
Firebase has strict requirements for User Property names; they must:

    Begin with a letter (not a number or symbol, including an underscore)
    Contain only alphanumeric characters and underscores
    Be no longer than 40 characters
```

I registered my new app on Firebase and got my `GoogleService-Info.plist` and `google-services.json` integrated in `app.json` as follow

```
"ios": {
  "bundleIdentifier": "com.company.appname",
  "buildNumber": ...,
  "googleServicesFile": "./assets/firebase/GoogleService-Info.plist",
  "infoPlist": {
    ...
  }
},
"android": {
  "package": "com.axiory.myaxiory",
  "googleServicesFile": "./assets/firebase/google-services.json",
  "versionCode": ...
}
```

I am successfully getting all the logs through Segment but not in Firebase. I follow this tutorial (for Android and iOS native codes) but without lack. https://segment.com/docs/connections/destinations/catalog/firebase/

Do you see what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Were you able to figure this out?

Comment: yes you have to implement it through website interface https://docs.expo.io/guides/setup-native-firebase/

Comment: sorry, yes I figured out. At the moment there is no possibility to run Firebase on Segment through Expo because you have to start plugins for Segment through native code and this is only possible if you eject application. My solution was to implement it Firebase separately with the own library.

Comment: Is there any way you can send me an example? I asked a question here describing my issue, if you leave an answer there that would really help me out. Sorry to inconvenience you. I am using Expo Managed workflow, SDK 40. My Question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65947994/analytics-not-working-in-react-native-app

Comment: you have to run all configs for firebase from app.json as described in link above. Than init in ts/js. From your question I do not see any point on the same question